# How to truncate working directory in prompt to show first and last folder?

Tags: macos, bash, prompt

I'm looking for a way to implement a responsive working directory where I at least want to display the first and last folder.
It should be based on the available with in the terminal. E.g. something like `$(expr`tput cols`- 35)}`.

Imagine the current working directory is `~/workspace/i/keep/my/projects/project1/src`

Then I would like to display the prompt like:

`~/workspace/../src`

If the terminal is big enough I would like to have:

`~/workspace/../project1/src`

or

`~/workspace/../projects/project1/src`

`~/workspace/../my/projects/project1/src`

and so forward.

If there is enough place it should even display the full path.
To win space the home dir should always be displayed like `~`.

Is this possible using a pure bash script on OSX?

Comment: I think it's possible. You can set PS1 as export PS1="\u@\h `~/somedir/koba.sh` > ". Then create this script (koba.sh) or anyname you like. In that script, use `pwd` and just use one "echo" statement to echo the format that you want ~/workspace/../xx/zz" or whatever after calculating what you want to echo as output (which will consider value of Environment variable COLUMNS (of the session window) i.e. it should change PS1 each time you use mouse to minimize/maximize your screen size. One important point to note is, if you are in ~/workspace folder, then your PS1 should not echo ~/../workspace

Comment: I posted a base script for you to look at. If you enhance it a little bit, you'll get what you need. I tested it on my machine and it's working as soon as I'm minimizing/maximizing the screen, though, I had to re-export PS1 (may be there's a way to auto set PS1)

Comment: I remember wanting something like this a couple of years ago. But then I decided to put a `\n` at the end of my prompt, just before the `\$`. Liberation! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Solution for the Simplest Case

> I would like to display the prompt like: `~/workspace/../src`

This will display that style of path while ending the prompt with the usual `$` and space:

```
PS1='$(pwd | sed -E -e "s|^$HOME|~|" -e '\''s|^([^/]*/[^/]*/).*(/[^/]*)|\1..\2|'\'') \$ '
```

Although my intention was that this work on OSX's BSD `sed`, I have only tested it on Linux with GNU `sed`.

This version provides only the one output format.  It does not change format as the terminal gets wider.

#### How it works

The key element in the definition of the new `PS1` is the command substitution.  That command is:

```
pwd | sed -E -e "s|^$HOME|~|" -e 's|^([^/]*/[^/]*/).*(/[^/]*)|\1..\2|'
```

- `pwd`

  This prints the current working directory to stdout
- `"s|^$HOME|~|"`

  If the path begins with `$HOME`, replace it with `~`.  Because `$HOME` is a shell variable, this command has to be in double-quotes so that the shell does variable substitution on `$HOME`.
- `'s|^([^/]*/[^/]*/).*(/[^/]*)|\1..\2|'`

  The regex consists of three parts:

  - `^([^/]*/[^/]*/)` matches the first two directories and saves them in `\1`.
  - `.*` this matches whatever follows the first two directories up until the last directory
  - `(/[^/]*)` matches the last subdirectory and saves it in `\2`.

  If there are enough directories for the regex to match, then the whole path is replaced with `\1..\2`.

### More Complex Solution

Suppose that we want the format of the prompt to change with the available width of the terminal, showing more of the final directories if there is space to do so.  Thus, in a narrow terminal, `/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` might be displayed as `~/dir1/../dir4` but in a wider terminal it would appear as  `~/dir1/../dir3/dir4` and in a still wider terminal, it would appear as `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`.

In that case:

```
PS1='$(pwd|awk -F/ -v "n=$(tput cols)" -v "h=^$HOME" '\''{sub(h,"~");n=0.3*n;b=$1"/"$2} length($0)<=n || NF==3 {print;next;} NF>3{b=b"/../"; e=$NF; n-=length(b $NF); for (i=NF-1;i>3 && n>length(e)+1;i--) e=$i"/"e;} {print b e;}'\'') \$ '
```

Because this solution requires more calculations, `awk` is used.

This code allows the user to adjust how much of the width of the terminal should be taken up by the directory list.  This is done by adjusting the constant in the code `n=0.3*n`.  As written, this restricts the directory display, if possible, to only 30% of the terminal width.

#### How it works

The key element of the code is this command:

```
pwd | awk -F/ -v "n=$(tput cols)" -v "h=^$HOME" '{sub(h,"~");n=0.3*n;b=$1"/"$2} length($0)<=n || NF==3 {print;next;} NF>3{b=b"/../"; e=$NF; n-=length(b $NF); for (i=NF-1;i>3 && n>length(e)+1;i--) e=$i"/"e;} {print b e;}'
```

The code considers these cases:

1. The directory string is short enough already.  In other words, its length is fits in the allotted space.  In this case, it is displayed as is.
2. There are only three directories.  For example, `~/dir1/dir2`.  Our format does not allow this to be shortened.  Thus, for this case, directory string is displayed as is.
3. There are four or more directories and the directory string must be shortened to fit in the space.  In this case, the directory string is divided into the beginning, which is stored in the variable `b`, and the ending, which is stored in the variable `e`.  The beginning contains two directories and the dot-dot string, such as `~/dir1/../`.  Starting from the last directory, directories are added to the end string `e` as space allows.

#### More details on the `awk` command

- `-F/`

  This sets the field separator to `/`.  As a consequence, each directory will appear as a separate field.
- `-v "n=$(tput cols)" -v "h=^$HOME"`

  This creates two variables that we will need.  `n` has the width of the terminal in columns.  `h` has a regex matching the the user's home directory.
- `sub(h,"~")`

  If the path starts with the user's home directory, this replaces it with a `~`.
- `n=0.3*n`

  This sets a goal for the desired width of the directory string in the prompt.  I like the directory string to be not too long, so `n=0.3*n` sets the goal to 30% of the width of the terminal in columns.  As discussed elsewhere, this can be replaced with another formula as per your personal preferences.
- `b=$1"/"$2`

  `b` is the variable that contains the beginning of the directory string.  Here, we set it to the first two directories.  If the path, for example, was `~/dir1/dir2/dir3`, then this sets `b` to `~/dir1`.
- `length($0)<=n || NF==3 {print;next;}`

  If the complete directory string is no longer than our goal, `n`, or else if there are only three directories in the directory string, then print out the directory string as is and then quit.
- `NF>3{b=b"/../"; e=$NF; n-=length(b $NF); for (i=NF-1;i>3 && n>length(e)+1;i--) e=$i"/"e;}`

  If we get, then our directory string needs to be shortened.  So, we add the abbreviation string `/../` to the end of `b`.  For the first trial, we set the end string, `e`, to be the last directory.  (In `awk`, `NF` is the number of fields.  So, `$NF` is the last field (directory) on the line.)  We then subtract from `n` the length of `b` and `e`.  The value of `n` that remains is the amount of space that we have left.  Then starting with the second to last directory on the line, we try to add one directory at a time to `e` without going over our goal for how long the directory string should be.
- `{print b e;}`

  This prints the final directory string that is used in the prompt.

#### Full Width Display

To change the amount of space taken up by the directory display, we change the command that read `n=0.3*n` (which aimed for 30% width) to `n=1*n` (which aims for full width even if the `$` prompt overflows to the next line):

```
PS1='$(pwd|awk -F/ -v "n=$(tput cols)" -v "h=^$HOME" '\''{sub(h,"~");n=1*n;b=$1"/"$2} length($0)<=n || NF==3 {print;next;} NF>3{b=b"/../"; e=$NF; n-=length(b $NF); for (i=NF-1;i>3 && n>length(e)+1;i--) e=$i"/"e;} {print b e;}'\'') \$ '
```

Depending on your preferences, you may want other formulas.  For example, try `n=n-10` and it will try to leave some (but not many) available spaces for you at the end of the prompt.

PM2Ring suggested that the `$` prompt always be placed on the next line, to do that, we place a `\n` (newline) before the `\$` prompt:

```
PS1='$(pwd|awk -F/ -v "n=$(tput cols)" -v "h=^$HOME" '\''{sub(h,"~");n=1*n;b=$1"/"$2} length($0)<=n || NF==3 {print;next;} NF>3{b=b"/../"; e=$NF; n-=length(b $NF); for (i=NF-1;i>3 && n>length(e)+1;i--) e=$i"/"e;} {print b e;}'\'') \n\$ '
```

Comment: Thanks John. On Linux machine, I got the following error while setting this PS1. It says: sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: @ArunSangal In that case, use `sed -r` in place of `sed -E`.  On my GNU `sed` (v4.2.1), the two do the same thing and `-E` is the format that is compatible with BSD `sed`.

Comment: Thanks. Though it didn't resolve main request. Kindly clarify. My window (COLUMNS > 200) and your solution printed ~/topfolder/lastfolder (than ~/topfolder/full/path/to/lastfolder OR ~/topfolder/../lastfolder) I think that's the point in his request that, if width / COLUMNS are good enough to fit PWD path, then it should print full value of PWD in PS1 and if COLUMNS/windows size is less than the characters in full PWD, then it'll use ~/topfolder/../lastfolder (considering an exception case that, if you are actually in ~/short/dir folder, then it'd echo PS1 as ~/short/dir than ~/short/../dir)

Comment: @ArunSangal (1) It does not behave that way on my system.  I get the `..` before the basename on long paths.  If the replacement text in the sed command is properly entered, I don't see how it could be otherwise. If the path is actually `~/short/dir`, then the sed substitution, if the command is entered properly, does not happen, and what is printed is `~/short/dir`, __not__ `~/short/../dir`.  (2) If you have the interest and the time to develop the full solution that varies with COLUMNS, please go ahead and develop.  It if works well, I'll upvote you.

Comment: Thanks John. I agree, it depends on OS. Well, I just found PROMPT_COMMAND variable and using that (I don't have to reset PS1) and it's working. I created a base script as well (per my post).

Comment: That brings up one point. How can we tackle, if the lastfolder/leaffolder is very long i.e. "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz11111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222333333333333333333333333333333" to fit the screen. Even my solution won't work (that I posted above but it can be tweaked to make itself aware of this fact and show only few last characters i.e. "~/short/../...3333", NOTE: there's "no" slash just before "3333"). How about yours!

Comment: Just a minor point: Rather than using a bare `$` at the end of the prompt use `\$` and it will print as a `$` for a normal user but as `#` for root. See man bash PROMPTING.

Comment: Many tThanks John (and also Arun). When my terminal is wide it still truncates the dir, even if there is more than enough space to add another folder. When I make it even wider then 1 folder is added but still the truncation. It seems when terminal is wide it only uses half of the available width. Is there some max length maybe?

Comment: @MarcelOverdijk Yes, there is an adjustment for that.  See updated answer.  I preferred a short prompt so I originally set the goal for the directory string to take up 30% of the width.  I added an example where the directory string is allowed to take up the full width and information on how to experiment to get precisely what you want.  In my original code, the 30% goal was set by the line `n=0.3n`.  As shown in the updated answer, you can change that formula as you wish.

Comment: @PM2Ring Very good ideas!  I updated the answer to include your `\$` improvement everywhere.  I also added an example including your newline suggestion.

Comment: Hm, not sure why it works differently for me, but I had to change n>length($i) to be n>length(e). It seems like that's a typo, as you want the length of the string to be less than n, not the index of the path...

Comment: @GlenTakahashi I came to the same conclusion before seeing your comment. Works for me too. I've suggested s/length($i)/length(e) as an edit to the solution.

Comment: Very good!  @mgiuffrida and Glen Takahashi, I updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I created a base script (which still need some enhancement for doing the last calculation path to find out how much lpart(last part or suffix part) to display after "~/worksapce/../" (fpart or first part or prefix), otherwise, it'll work if you:
 **1. export COLUMNS** and 
**2. set your PS1** as "*export PS1="`~/somedir/koba.sh` $ "

I have tested the condition for ~/workspace folder as well when your COLUMNS value is less than echo `~/workspace | wc -c`. This base example script will only take lpart/suffix/last part as last folder only (as I'm using basename command). The only other thing, I saw was, I had to export PS1 each time (after minimizing/maximizing the window, but after that it worked as expected).

[giga@someserver somePS1]$ **cat ~/somedir/koba.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

## NOTE this script should echo only 1 echo output and exit out as soon as you echo 
## your first echo.

cdir=`pwd`
wc_dir=$(echo $cdir | wc -c)
bal=$(expr $COLUMNS - $wc_dir)

if [[ "`echo $(pwd) | tr '/' '\012'| wc -l`" -le 2 || $bal -ge $wc_dir ]];
then
 echo "`pwd`"; exit 0 ;
else
 fpart="$(echo $cdir | cut -d'/' -f1,2)/../"
 lpart="$(basename $cdir)"
 ## Calculate lpart (last part) in an better way to show ../aaa or ../aaa/bbb or ../aaa/bbb/c1 or more depending upon $COLUMNS and $wc_dir
 ## Do that math here.
 ## ...
 ## ...

 echo "${fpart}${lpart}"; exit 0;
fi
```

**OR**

After exporting those 2 ENV variables. If you:

just set the following ENVIRONMENT variable to the script. This variable calls the script each time before PS1 is displayed. Thus, it'll set the dir value and PS1 is set to display in the given format. Using this, now you do **NOT** have to reset PS1 each time your windows/screen size is changed or you move in your path to different parent/child folders. Just hit enter (minimize / maximize window) and see, it works!!!

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="~/somedir/koba.sh"
```

Comment: We need to find a way: How to "reset" PS1 as I mentioned above automatically as soon as after running any command at $ prompt OR as soon as someone changes the windows size (may be some setting in the editor itself exist for such size change for PS1).

Comment: OK, great. I found the final Answer. Good news. It's possible.

Comment: export PROMPT_COMMAND="~/somedir/koba.sh" ... this will do it. Now, minimize or maximize your screen and just hit enter key at $ prompt (NOT need to reset PS1 and)... it works like a charm.

Comment: There's only one flaw in this whole request (Not in my solution) that if the leaf folder is "sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooLoooooooooooooooooooooooNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGtttttttttooooooooPPPPPPPPPPPPPRINT" then, I doubt we can get this accomplished. Any idea!!! anyone.